# DRF: how to render relative urls as hyperlinks in the browsable api?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am exposing my api through an api gateway.
So absolute urls is a problem, I have to use relative url's.

So when creating the url, I do not send in the request. That creates relative urls.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=None, format=format),
        'snippets': reverse('snippet-list', request=None, format=format)
    })
```

From the frontend browsable api the urls do not show up as hyperlinks - when using this method. I want to allow a user to click through on the relative urls, instead of having to copy the link and add it to the browser url bar.

Is there a way to do this with Django Rest Framework? I know that the rest api for [AWX](https://github.com/ansible/awx) does it somehow.

Comment: What about this, [Relationships & Hyperlinked APIs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis/)

Comment: I hope, this is also useful, [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer)

Comment: Thanks @ArakkalAbu I have updated my question with reference to your links.

Comment: this is fixed in [DRF 3.14.0](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/releases/tag/3.14.0), [PR #8464](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/8464/files)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After investigating what awx was doing, they are using Javascript or jQuery to convert the relative url's.

As per [`api.js`](https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/awx/static/api/api.js)

```
// Make links from relative URLs to resources.
$('span.str').each(function() {
  var s = $(this).html();
  if (s.match(/^\"\/.+\/\"$/) || s.match(/^\"\/.+\/\?.*\"$/)) {
    $(this).html('"<a href=' + s + '>' + s.replace(/\"/g, '') + '</a>"');
  }
});
```

So included that in `templates/rest_framework/api.html`:

```
{% block script %}
<script>
  window.drf = {
    csrfHeaderName: "{{ csrf_header_name|default:'X-CSRFToken' }}",
    csrfToken: "{% if request %}{{ csrf_token }}{% endif %}"
  };
</script>
<script src="{% static "rest_framework/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "rest_framework/js/csrf.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "rest_framework/js/bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js" %}"></script>
<script src="{% static "rest_framework/js/default.js" %}"></script>

<script src="{% static "js/api.js" %}"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').ajaxForm();
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: IMHO, you don't need to play with js